# My Ruby install \bin\ruby.exe is not getting found when running rake_task for rspec

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, rake

I can run rspec directly but with a Rakefile as simple as

`require 'rspec/core/rake_task'`

`task :default => [:spec]`

`RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new do |task|`

`end`

I get something like this output
C:\Ruby193 -S rspec ./spec/hello_spec.rb

You can see that it has not found the ruby executable.
How does rspec know where it is?
I shut off my environment variable for Ruby and it still does this.

Comment: Am I missing something or shouldn't the second line of code be inside the block? So `task :default...` should be inside `RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new do |task| # put code here # end`

Comment: No that line declares the default task. I does not go into the block but you can try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set environment variables for two types so I could still find binaries in the main Ruby install.
First for user I put the entire path to ruby\bin\ruby.exe and for system I put just the path to the bin directory. This seemed to solve my problem and I can still run other binaries.

USER:
%RUBY% = C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe and append to PATH

SYSTEM:
%RUBY% = C:\Ruby193 and append this to Path as %RUBY%\bin

I use ansicon.exe plus the dll from root where ever as long as the same drive.

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

task :default => [:spec]

RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new do |task|
  task.pattern = "./spec/*_spec.rb"
  task.rspec_opts = ['-c']# for ansi colors
end
```

Note you do not need default in the block. task is the default which is test. Just set some options with it.